# How to ignore win32 exception? module process

Tags: c#, windows, com

I tried to create to look dll that loaded in process, but I got an error when getting process with system.dll. It throws this error message:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Unable to enumerate the process modules.'

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace dll
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process process in processlist)
            {
                foreach (ProcessModule module in process.Modules)
                {
                    if (module.FileName.Contains("foo.dll"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(module.FileName);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is this? How to fix this?

Comment: You can ignore it by a try catch block. But better is to solve the error. A stacktrace would be nice to solve this issue.

Comment: @MarkBaijens the truth i want is solve but i don't know what exactly the error. so better solve it. its better to skip it. since the dll i want search its not associative with system, local service privelege. top is administrator only.

Comment: Sidenote: this line `Process[] processlist Process.GetProcesses();` is missing an `=`

Comment: @MarkBaijens i think cause someone edit my article. in my real source code theres equal. but its not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the final answer but better fits here then in a comment.

Try using this code to catch the exception and print it to the console. Then you can see the full stacktrace in the console. With this stacktrace you can further resolve the error.

You probably trying to access a MainModule where you don't have access too.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
namespace dll {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            try {
                Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
                foreach(Process process in processlist) {
                    foreach(ProcessModule module in process.Modules) {
                        if(module.FileName.Contains("foo.dll")) {
                            Console.WriteLine(module.FileName);                           
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Win32Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

It probably fails on this line: `foreach(ProcessModule module in process.Modules)` so you know it can't access one or more of the modules. Probably due to system restrictions.

If you only want to check the modules and therefore accept that not all the modules are checked then you can do this.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
namespace dll {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int noErrorCount = 0;
            int errorCount = 0;
            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach(Process process in processlist) {

                try {
                    foreach(ProcessModule module in process.Modules) {
                        if(module.FileName.Contains("foo.dll")) {
                            Console.WriteLine(module.FileName);
                        }
                        noErrorCount++;
                    }
                }
                catch(Win32Exception ex) {
                    errorCount++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Modules checked: " + noErrorCount);
            Console.WriteLine("Modules with error(not checked): " + errorCount);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Code in an infinite loop

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
namespace dll {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            try {
                while(true) {
                    int noErrorCount = 0;
                    int errorCount = 0;
                    Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
                    foreach(Process process in processlist) {

                        try {
                            foreach(ProcessModule module in process.Modules) {
                                if(module.FileName.ToLower().Contains("Kernel32.dll".ToLower())) {
                                    Console.WriteLine(module.FileName);
                                }
                                //Console.WriteLine(module.FileName);
                                noErrorCount++;
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Win32Exception ex) {
                            errorCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Modules checked: " + noErrorCount);
                    Console.WriteLine("Modules with error(not checked): " + errorCount);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as u see what the problem here? realy don't know what the thrown tell me and how to fix it. i want to create some feature like antivirus that search suspicious process by dll. since every process need some unique dll to run. if i search by process name. its easy to bypass cause it need only  change file name. and that process can run again.

Comment: the output i want is not a count's dll but the path dll. like when no win32 exception thrown. but its almost achieve

Comment: `foreach(ProcessModule module in process.Modules)` doesn't let you access all the the module either because of security issues or difference of 32/64 bit.

Comment: from your code we see the result theres 2 dll that error dont allow to checked. then how we only skip that dll. and process other?

Comment: The path of the dll is printed only if it contains "foo.dll". I kept your code the same. The counts are just as feedback to you what happend. You can remove those if you don't want them.

Comment: "then how we only skip that dll. and process other?" The try catch block does exactly this already. But you probably want to change `foo.dll` to the dll you are looking for.

Comment: i tried to run an application and try search the dll i want. its not print i can see dll from process explorer by windows.

Comment: Then there is no module with that filename since the code is working here when i search for a filename that exists in a module.

Comment: Note: your code is case sensitive.

Comment: This removes case sensitivity. `if(module.FileName.ToLower().Contains("Kernel32.dll".ToLower()))`

Comment: i think this exception dont work. like it stop search until that 2 error appear like no exception and are u believe only 3k dll load in process?. cause the dll i want to search not appear. it only appear system dll. not the appl;ication dll that load. if u belieave the dll i want to look is cps.dll. its a ragnarok unique dll that ragnarok exe need.

Comment: i try to run openkore and see XSTools.dll run in process by process explorer. but no result in this application. its like its not find entire dll run in machine. it stop execution when error occur.

Comment: It does not stop execution when a error occurs. (unless it's a different error)  I got 97 errors on my own machine. It stops when all modules are iterated trough. However it only check the filename of a module. But 1 dll can depend on another dll. This way modules probably can have more than 1 dll while your code only checks the filename of the module. (I don't know anything about the tools you are mentioning)

Comment: ok u can try add infinite loop with while(true){} look the error occur in IDE. it will stop execution.

Comment: Did you remove the `Console.ReadLine()`? Since it works fine here.

Comment: for what Console.Readline? this's a checker module thats mean it should run in infinite loop.

Comment: `Console.Readline()` is a command to read user input from the console. It is used here as a tool to keep the console open after the code completes. If you don't add this line at the end of your code and your code is done then the console will be closed automatically. But in an infinite while loop you don't need that of course. Or leave it out of the while loop as a fallback mechanism if you use exception handling on the loop.

Comment: Added working code in an infinite loop in my answer.

Comment: I think i will give up to add feature search process by dll. its seem dont work, dll don't show in specific program like openkore, cheat engine sometime show sometimes not. i don't know why. conclusion its not effective to add this feature.  i will stick to binary open analyze and scan files. by the way do you know. how open box with display image and will close after 3 seconds. i need it for build my logo when launch my app in console. thx

Comment: Bajens i think our solution is this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx